# How can I wrap std::format() with my own template function?

Tags: c++, c++20, variadic-templates, fmt

Note:  this question uses C++20, and I'm using Visual Studio 2022 (v17.2.2).

I would like to create a template function wrapper to allow me to use std::format style logging.  The wrapper function will eventually do some other non-format related stuff that is not important here.

Refer to the code below.  Note that **Log1()** works fine, but feels clunky to use.  **Log2()** is ok, but using **std::vformat()** loses compile-time checking of log format strings.

What I really want to do is **Log3()**.  Problem is that Visual Studio (v17.2.2) doesn't like this.

Is there any way I can get this to work (without macros)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <format>
#include <string_view>
 
// works fine:  usage is clunky
auto Log1(std::string_view sv)
{
    std::cout << sv;
}
 
// works, but fmt string is checked at runtime - not compile time
template<typename... Args>
auto Log2(std::string_view fmt, Args&&... args)
{
    std::cout << std::vformat(fmt, std::make_format_args(args...));
}
 
// this doesn't work
template<typename... Args>
auto Log3(std::string_view fmt, Args&&... args)
{
    std::cout << std::format(fmt, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
 
int main()
{
    Log1(std::format("Hello, {}\n", "world!")); // ok - clunky
    Log2("Hello, {}\n", "world!");              // ok - no compile time checking of fmt string
    Log2("Hello, {:s}\n", 42);                  // ok - throws at runtime
    Log3("Hello, {}\n", "world!");              // ERROR:  doesn't compile
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pasting the compiler errors in question might help others to answer it more quickly.

Comment: In msvc v19.latest, I see the [error](https://godbolt.org/z/53a6q57W6) which is "format(2963): note: failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need [P2508](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2508r1.html) (my paper) to land, which exposes the currently exposition-only type `std::basic-format-string<charT, Args...>`, which will allow you to write:

```cpp
template<typename... Args>
auto Log3(std::format_string<Args...> fmt, Args&&... args)
```

---

Until then, you can just be naughty and use the MSVC implementation's internal helper for this, with understanding that they can rename this type at will at any point.

```cpp
template<typename... Args>
auto Log3(std::_Fmt_string<Args...> fmt, Args&&... args)
```

Comment: Is it the standard version of `fmt::format_string`?

Comment: @LouisGo Yes it is.

Comment: Barry - you are a legend!  Thank you for your answer.  I shall follow the P2508 paper - hopefully comes soon.  For now will do as you suggest and use **std::_Fmt_string** directly.

Comment: Even with `std::format_string`, it does not seem to work: https://godbolt.org/z/7hvnePYd4

Comment: @LukeZhou That's because you're not using `std::format_string`, you have to actually use it: https://godbolt.org/z/b68cddEE7

Comment: @Barry Looks like the key is using `std::basic_format_string<char, std::type_identity_t<Args>...>` instead of `std::basic_format_string<char, Args...>`. Was wondering how type deduction would work. Thanks for the reply!